# Can I add a custom http header to SOAP message

Tags: asp.net, soap

Can I add a custom headers to the following headers

```
POST /InStock HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.org
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: nnn

<?xml version="1.0"?>
 .....
```

please any help ?

Comment: How are you constructing your SOAP message? Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write an **HttpModule** to **intercept** WebService **Response** and add your custom header in the intercepted response stream.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see this bug report, the answer is at 2010-07-23 05:59 UTC

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51551&edit=2